# Collision Detection in Java for a game

Tags: java, collision-detection

Im making a game in Java with a few other people but we are stuck on one part of it, making the collision detection. The game is an RPG and I know how to do the collision detection with the characters using Rectangles, but what I dont know how to do is the collision detection for the maps. What I mean by that is like so the character cant walk over trees or water and that stuff but using rectangles doesnt seem like the best option here.

Well to explain what the game maps are gonna look like, here is an example http://i980.photobucket.com/albums/ae287/gordsmash/7-8.jpg

Now I could use rectangles to get bounds and stop the player from walking over the trees and water but that would take a lot of them.

But is there another easier way to prevent the player from walking over the trees and obstacles besides using Rectangles?

Comment: This would be good for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way but it uses more memory and you do the work up front... just create a background collision mask that denotes the permissible areas for characters to walk on in a binary form. You can store that in some sort of compressed bitmap form.  The lookup then is very simple and very quick.

Comment: That does seem like a very great way to do collision detection, but I was wondering how I would program that? I think we were thinking about doing that before but we didnt know how we would get the coordinates of every corner and side of a large object like that.

Comment: You essentially load a copy of your background image into an editor and manually (if you can't do it programmatically) draw over all the areas to create the collision mask; black for walkable, white for impassable.  If you're using tiles you do this once for each tile type. As the sprite moves you fetch a rectangle from the mask which would represent its new position, or create a rectangle from several tile collision masks as necessary.  You can then AND this with the sprite mask and check the result for any non-zero pixels.  If there are any, you've had a collision and abort the move.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle collision detection seems to make sense; However, alternatively you may also try sphere-sphere collision detection, which can detect collision much quicker. You don't even need a square root for distance computations since you can compare the squared distances to see if the spheres overlap. This is a very fast method, and given the nature of your game could work very well.

ALSO! Assuming you have numerous tiles which you are colliding against, consider some method of spacial partitioning. Let me give you an easy example - subdivide your map into several rectangles (http://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/qiuhua.liang/Research/Pic_research/mine_grid.jpg) and then depending on which rectangular area your player is currently residing in - check collision only against the tiles which are located within that area.

You may take it a step further - if you have more tiles in any given area than the threshold that you set - subdivide that area further to make more smaller areas within it.

The idea behind such subdivision is called Quadtree, and there is a huge quantity of papers and tutorials on the subject, you'll catch on very quickly.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this type of problem, but for what you're doing I believe the best course of action would be to use a tile engine.  This would have been commonly used in similar games in the past (think any RPG on the SNES) and it provides you with a quick and easy means of both level/map design and collision detection.

The basic concept of a tile engine is that objects are stored in a 2D array and when your player (or any other moving game entity) attempts to move into a new tile you perform a simple check to see if the object in that tile is passable or not (for instance, if it's grass, the player may move; if it's a treasure chest, the player cannot move).  This will greatly simplify checking for collisions (as a naive check of a list of entities will have O(n^2) performance).  [This picture](http://i50.tinypic.com/nntbuo.jpg) might give you an idea of what I'm talking about.  The lines have been added to illustrate a point, but of course when you're playing the game you don't actively think of everything as being composed of individual 32x32 pixel tiles.

While I don't personally have any experience with tile engines in Java, it looks like [Mappy](http://tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php) supports Java, and I've heard good things about [PulpCore](http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/).  You're more than welcome to create your own engine, of course, but you have to decide if your effort is better spent reinventing the wheel (but, of course, it will be *your* wheel then, and that is rather satisfying) or spend your time making a better game.